# Exporting Java project as .jar file will complain that certain .java files aren't found

Tags: java, eclipse

When trying to export a project as a `.jar` file, Eclipse will complain that some files can't be found on the classpath:

> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'proj/src/main/java/analysis/specification/VerifyVariableIsDefinedInsideTargetTerm.java'

Now, the interesting part is that these files haven't actually existed on the disk for ages. I guess I force Eclipse to refresh its database some way. I've tried doing F5 for a full build, but it seems to no avail. I've also tried the procedure described in [this blog post](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2009/11/10/how-to-fix-a-broken-eclipse-environment-without-starting-completely-from-scratch/), but the issue remains.

Comment: This question should not be closed. It's obviously not local to a time or place. Getting errors when creating a jar using eclipse is exactly the right scope of a question for stackoverflow. Not only was I getting this exact error message. The first answer was the exact solution.

Comment: I Googled and it seems there are many other people with this problem. I was able to fix it on my environment and I wanted share my solution with you but the question is closed ! In my case my .class files were not created and therefore when I was trying to create the jar file then it would give me the above error. so, here is what I did In Eclipse/STS, un-check  the Automatically build and then click project clean build (select you specific project).

Comment: @user717630: vote to reopen, if you can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Error… I actually tripped on the reason for the problem a few moments ago…

All the files that were raising problems did actually exist on the project but were commented out (and thus, I didn't see them in the package explorer which is the view I generally use).

After deleting them, everything went fine. I still don't understand why would they raise errors in the JAR creation process, though…

**EDIT:**
Here's an example of a commented out class:

```
package a.b.c

//import java.io.Closeable;

//public class Example implements Closeable {
//    public void close() throws IOException {
//        System.out.println("closed");
//    }
//}
```

Because the whole class is commented out, no `Example.class` is created. Whereas if the class is commented out like this:

```
package a.b.c

//import java.io.Closeable;

public class Example
//    implements Closeable
{
//    public void close() throws IOException {
//        System.out.println("closed");
//    }
}
```

an `Example.class` is created, although empty.

This may be a bug in eclipse. If you export the ant build script from eclipse and use that, it creates the JAR just fine.

Comment: Very strange issue, but your answer was spot-on; I had pulled out a piece of my application for use as a [mostly] independent module, but left the original class(es) in place, but wholly commented out. There were no references to the original class, but I wasn't yet prepared to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurred to me also. However, the problem that I had was that I had JRE configuration issues in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the real problem is that not all your class files are in the same place… My suggestion is to move all your `.java` files into the same folder, recompile to make the `.class` files, make sure all the `.class` files are then in the same folder… Then, check out this [webpage](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/), if you need any help on actually creating the `.jar`.

The website also assumes you are on a Mac, but you should still be able to use a command prompt on Windows to get it work.

Comment: @Sae1962 If you are to edit answers/questions, please take the time to make it worthwile for reviewers.