# Eclipse - JAR creation failed "Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for..."

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I have a project in Eclipse that has a red cross on it and will not export to a runnable JAR. I can't remember if I have looked at it since I reinstalled Windows on my laptop, but I know that I haven't changed any code. There are no errors in any of the classes, however the error I get points to the following class that deals with the menu items on Mac OSx:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class osxhandler implements InvocationHandler {

    protected Object targetObject;
    protected Method targetMethod;
    protected String proxySignature;

    static Object macOSXApplication;

    // Pass this method an Object and Method equipped to perform application shutdown logic
    // The method passed should return a boolean stating whether or not the quit should occur
    public static void setQuitHandler(Object target, Method quitHandler) {
        setHandler(new HOsx("handleQuit", target, quitHandler));
    }


    public static void setAboutHandler(Object target, Method aboutHandler) {
        boolean enableAboutMenu = (target != null && aboutHandler != null);
        if (enableAboutMenu) {
            setHandler(new HOsx("handleAbout", target, aboutHandler));
        }
        // If we're setting a handler, enable the About menu item by calling
        // com.apple.eawt.Application reflectively
        try {
            Method enableAboutMethod = macOSXApplication.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setEnabledAboutMenu", new Class[] { boolean.class });
            enableAboutMethod.invoke(macOSXApplication, new Object[] { Boolean.valueOf(enableAboutMenu) });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("MacOSHandler could not access the About Menu");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

       public static void setPreferencesHandler(Object target, Method prefsHandler) {
            boolean enablePrefsMenu = (target != null && prefsHandler != null);
            if (enablePrefsMenu) {
                setHandler(new HOsx("handlePreferences", target, prefsHandler));
            }
            // If we're setting a handler, enable the Preferences menu item by calling
            // com.apple.eawt.Application reflectively
            try {
                Method enablePrefsMethod = macOSXApplication.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setEnabledPreferencesMenu", new Class[] { boolean.class });
                enablePrefsMethod.invoke(macOSXApplication, new Object[] { Boolean.valueOf(enablePrefsMenu) });
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println("MacOSHandler could not access the About Menu");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Pass this method an Object and a Method equipped to handle document events from the Finder
        // Documents are registered with the Finder via the CFBundleDocumentTypes dictionary in the 
        // application bundle's Info.plist
        public static void setFileHandler(Object target, Method fileHandler) {
            setHandler(new HOsx("handleOpenFile", target, fileHandler) {
                // Override MacOSHandler.callTarget to send information on the
                // file to be opened
                public boolean callTarget(Object appleEvent) {
                    if (appleEvent != null) {
                        try {
                            Method getFilenameMethod = appleEvent.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getFilename", (Class[])null);
                            String filename = (String) getFilenameMethod.invoke(appleEvent, (Object[])null);
                            this.targetMethod.invoke(this.targetObject, new Object[] { filename });
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        // setHandler creates a Proxy object from the passed MacOSHandler and adds it as an ApplicationListener
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        public static void setHandler(HOsx adapter) {
            try {
                Class applicationClass = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.Application");
                if (macOSXApplication == null) {
                    macOSXApplication = applicationClass.getConstructor((Class[])null).newInstance((Object[])null);
                }
                Class applicationListenerClass = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener");
                Method addListenerMethod = applicationClass.getDeclaredMethod("addApplicationListener", new Class[] { applicationListenerClass });
                // Create a proxy object around this handler that can be reflectively added as an Apple ApplicationListener
                Object MacOSHandlerProxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(HOsx.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { applicationListenerClass }, adapter);
                addListenerMethod.invoke(macOSXApplication, new Object[] { MacOSHandlerProxy });
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                System.err.println("This version of Mac OS X does not support the Apple EAWT.  ApplicationEvent handling has been disabled (" + cnfe + ")");
            } catch (Exception ex) {  // Likely a NoSuchMethodException or an IllegalAccessException loading/invoking eawt.Application methods
                System.err.println("Mac OS X Adapter could not talk to EAWT:");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Each MacOSHandler has the name of the EAWT method it intends to listen for (handleAbout, for example),
        // the Object that will ultimately perform the task, and the Method to be called on that Object
        protected HOsx(String proxySignature, Object target, Method handler) {
            this.proxySignature = proxySignature;
            this.targetObject = target;
            this.targetMethod = handler;
        }

        // Override this method to perform any operations on the event 
        // that comes with the various callbacks
        // See setFileHandler above for an example
        public boolean callTarget(Object appleEvent) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
            Object result = targetMethod.invoke(targetObject, (Object[])null);
            if (result == null) {
                return true;
            }
            return Boolean.valueOf(result.toString()).booleanValue();
        }

        // InvocationHandler implementation
        // This is the entry point for our proxy object; it is called every time an ApplicationListener method is invoked
        public Object invoke (Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (isCorrectMethod(method, args)) {
                boolean handled = callTarget(args[0]);
                setApplicationEventHandled(args[0], handled);
            }
            // All of the ApplicationListener methods are void; return null regardless of what happens
            return null;
        }

        // Compare the method that was called to the intended method when the MacOSHandler instance was created
        // (e.g. handleAbout, handleQuit, handleOpenFile, etc.)
        protected boolean isCorrectMethod(Method method, Object[] args) {
            return (targetMethod != null && proxySignature.equals(method.getName()) && args.length == 1);
        }

        // It is important to mark the ApplicationEvent as handled and cancel the default behavior
        // This method checks for a boolean result from the proxy method and sets the event accordingly
        protected void setApplicationEventHandled(Object event, boolean handled) {
            if (event != null) {
                try {
                    Method setHandledMethod = event.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setHandled", new Class[] { boolean.class });
                    // If the target method returns a boolean, use that as a hint
                    setHandledMethod.invoke(event, new Object[] { Boolean.valueOf(handled) });
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("MacOSHandler was unable to handle an ApplicationEvent: " + event);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

Any ideas as to why I can't export/compile? I've never had this issue before.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Don't think so... How do I do that?

Comment: Look in the `Project` menu

Comment: @adarshr Found it. It compiles now, thank you, would you like to add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126985/exporting-java-project-as-jar-file-will-complain-that-certain-java-files-aren/12435319#12435319

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just do a clean and/or rebuild on the project.

You can find it under the `Project` menu of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to accept yours seeing as though you gave me the solution the quickest. :) Any idea why this worked tough?

Comment: Simply because Eclipse last compiled your code before you re-installed Windows. Now it can't find some or all of the class files. So, by doing a clean + rebuild, you'll be telling Eclipse to discard any existing class files and recompile from scratch. Usually we do this as the first step before starting any new work, just to rule out inconsistencies.

Comment: Messing with 'Clean' wiped out my entire project. The restore from history only recovered a few classes. Thought I might just share that

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 8):

I also had a different, degenerate case of this problem. Turned out, we had a class in our project that had a file (so Eclipse kept it on the classpath) but no actual class defined in the file (the file only had imports and a class comment... probably a merge gone wrong). Anyway, deleting the file solved the issue.

Comment: In my case a whole class was commented out.

Answer (score 4):

> It’s quite hateful that Eclipse always generates hidden files .project
>   and .classpath in project folder. Sometimes you’re not aware if
>   something goes wrong in these files.
>
> After upgrading your Eclipse and if you found the following compile
>   error, I’d suggest you to check .classpath in your project folder.
>
> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project
>
> Most likely you would see a line like this.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/j2re1.4.2_03"/>
```

> The stupid Eclipse appended this for no reason. Just simply remove it
>   to make it work again. ;)
>
> /org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/j2re1.4.2_xx

Source: http://hochit.com/2006/07/06/eclipse-upgrading-problem-javalangobject-not-found/

In addition, you can check your `project settings` in eclipse. Right click on your project and choose properties. Go to Java Build Path and there should be more specific information of the problem. Most likely you set the `JDK` to an Version which doesn't exist on the new System.

If this doesn't help too, select your project and then use the menu entry `Source->Clean Up`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. I didn't need to do the first part though, I just did a clean :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **the classes were empty**, and the compiler whined:

```
Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'ibDemo/src/com/ib/controller/LocationCode.java'
Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for: 'ibDemo/src/com/ib/controller/PairPanel.java'
```

To solve this I'd to add a class declaration:

```
public class LocationCode
{

}
```

and

```
public class PairPanel
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got referred here, because I had the same error.
I am using maven on eclipse. I did right click on repo, chose build path->Conifgure build->Project References and checked the project references for my repo. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. In my case problem was, I had put same jar multiple times once through "user library" & next time through "build path" on the same Project. Just deleted the repeated jars from the classpath & got ride of the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and after trying out multiple recommendations, nothing had worked out. So I created a new workspace and refer to this project. After that, it got successfully built and exported the JAR without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this might be the best possible solution, but do check java build path. I had it pointing to a wrong location because of which I was facing class not found error. 
Once java build path was fixed, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I came here on same error.  In my case, nothing was compiling (building?) and Eclipse didn't tell me there was any issue with the build other than these cryptic messages.  I eventually unzipped the jar file and saw that it had no classes in it.  It was because because the project I referenced in my build path wasn't built.  In my case, the project would not compile in a million years, but I had access to jar files from R&D dept who could and did compile it in their own way.  So I referenced those jar files instead.  Now my classes compile and the error went away.  I'm sure I would have done that in the first place but "Helpful" Eclipse suggested for me to reference the unbuilt project so I went along with the bad suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I closed all tabs with files in Eclipse, and it's fixed problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same problem and I noticed I mvn clean and tried to export the jar and end-up getting the same error.
It worked for me after mvn install.